# Lendo txt com StreamReader

Tags: c#

Ao ler um arquivo TXT, de lançamentos contábeis exportando por um sistema de terceiro, sendo o meu problema nas linhas que possuí o NÂº.

> VLR REF ALGUMA COISA NÂº 1834 MAIS TEXTO

Utilizando a classe `StreamReader` da seguinte forma

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Projetos\Syns\Documentação\Contabilidade\exemplo.txt"))
{
    string actual = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Assert.AreEqual("VLR REF ALGUMA COISA NÂº 1834 MAIS TEXTO", actual);
}
```

O que tenho como retorno na **string actual** é

> VLR REF ALGUMA COISA N?? 1834 MAIS TEXTO

sendo que preciso que retorno o valor igual ao do arquivo texto.

Que tipo de ***enconding*** tenho que usar nessa situação?

Comment: tente `new StreamReader(@"D:\Projetos\Syns\Documentação\Contabilidade\exemplo.txt", Encoding.Default)`

Comment: Utilizando dessa maneira me resolveu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O mais comum é UTF8, mas você também pode tentar com ANSI

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Projetos\Syns\Documentação\Contabilidade\exemplo.txt", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
     string actual = reader.ReadToEnd();
     Assert.AreEqual("VLR REF ALGUMA COISA NÂº 1834 MAIS TEXTO", actual);
}
```

---

EDIT:
Como visto nos comentários, pelo @RovannLinhalis Enconding.Default foi a solução para o problema.

Comment: Com UTF8 não rolou, como que fica com ANSI?

Comment: System.Text.Encoding.ANSI, cola na sua pergunta um trecho do arquivo de texto.

Comment: Mas eu coloquei um trecho.

Comment: Esse é todo o conteúdo do arquivo ou ele é composto por várias linhas? você verificou o encoding em que o arquivo foi gravado?

Comment: É um arquivo de lançamentos contábeis que é exportado por um sistema externo, não sei em que enconding ele é exportado. Tenho mais linhas sim nesse arquivo eu só extrai a parte que afeta a leitura para simplificar a pergunta, pois meu problema é quando tem NÂº na linha.